# on gimp i have a picture which has a green effect i need to make it back to normal?

Tags: gimp

I have a picture where the image has a green shade to it. I think it has been done in the levels button. I need to get the image colours back to normal but can't get it right using the levels so was wondering if there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Under **Colours** -> **Levels**, the **All Channels** section has 4 buttons, **Auto**, plus 3 pickers for black, grey and white. **Auto** does a fair job, but otherwise click on one of the pickers and then on an area of the image which should be black/grey/white and has a noticeable green cast and the cast is immediately removed.

See http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/gimptutorials/ss/Correct-White-Balance_2.htm for a more detailed discussion.